# how to create tkinter entry box with multiline

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

How to create large extry box in python tkinter?
I have tried to use `height` in ttk.entry() but the error show :

> _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-height"

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
GUI = Tk()
GUI.title("myTest")
GUI.geometry("700x700")

S_NOTE = StringVar()
E_NOTE = ttk.Entry(GUI, textvariable = S_NOTE, font = FONT1, width = 40, height = 20)
E_NOTE.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, rowspan = 2)

GUI.mainloop()
```

I also need to get the StringVar from the entrybox and fix the position (such as using grid)

Comment: Why don't you use `Text` widget instead?

Comment: @acw1668 plase tell me about the text

Comment: I also need to get the StringVar and fix the position (such as using grid)

Comment: You cannot use `StringVar` with a `Text` widget.  See official [document](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/text.htm).

Comment: @VittawatLaorungroj what are you using the `StringVar` for? Most of the `StringVar` methods are implemented in the `tkinter.Text` widget in 1 form or another.

Comment: Please do a little research before asking such a basic question. Most tkinter tutorials will likely tell you that the Text widget is for multiline input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using a bad way to do this..
see.. You can use the Text widget to do the same..
Example:

```
from tkinter import *
GUI = Tk()
GUI.title("myTest")
GUI.geometry("700x700")

def set_text_to_variable():
    global E_NOTE
    global S_NOTE
    S_NOTE = E_NOTE.get(1.0,END)
    print("S_NOTE = ",S_NOTE)

E_NOTE = Text(GUI, font = "Segoe", width = 40, height = 20)
E_NOTE.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, rowspan = 2)

Change_variable = Button(GUI, text = "CHANGE THE \"S_NOTE\" VARIABLE", command = set_text_to_variable)
Change_variable.grid()

GUI.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think you assumed that OP needs the text variable to get data out of the `tk.Text`. What if OP is using the variable to change the data in `tk.Text`?